# What happened on the Pakled ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "Brothers," Lore explains that after he was beamed off of the ship in "Datalore" he drifted in space---until a passing Pakled ship picked him up.

Nothing in canon speaks to this, but does anything in non-canon talk about what happened on the Pakled vessel? Given Lore's superiority, he surely took over the ship quite easily. Though I'm not sure if that included violence or something else.

Comment: They drifted in space until they found people to help them go

Comment: I've since looked through more EU literature, and can't find anything else beyond what I've put below.  If you feel like the answer has been useful to you, you may want to accept it.  (No pressure.)  :-)

Comment: What happens on the Pakled ship, stays on the Pakled ship.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, there is a very interesting Extended Universe story on the matter.

In the *TNG* short story ["I Am Become Death"](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/I_Am_Become_Death), the "Children of Soong" (Soongian-type androids like Data, Lore, and B-4)

> are, by the 44th Century, in control of much of the galaxy and begin systematically suppressing and wiping out organic humanoid life.  Data is still alive and functional at this time, but laments the course of events.  Commandeering a Federation timeship, Data travels back to the 24th Century believing that if he hadn't transported Lore into space, Lore would have continued on a path that would have discredited androids.  Data believes that his own reputation as a "good android" allowed androids to gain the trust of humanity, thus paving the way for android rule.  Now in 2364, Data takes over a Pakled ship in the vicinity of where he expects Lore to be drifting.  They find him, but he is damaged beyond repair.  Data subsequently decides that he himself will assume the role of Lore.

The implication is that the Lore we see in "Descent" Parts I and II is *actually Data*.  Ironically, the 24th Century Data disables and dismantles him and so history possibly repeats itself.

Comment: That's interesting,  but even if 24th-century Data disables 44th-century Data posing as Lore, how does history repeat itself?   Lore is still out of the picture.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I'm not sure what you mean.  The story implies that future Data failed and so the Soongian Empire still rises and enslaves humanity.

Comment: Ok,  i get it.   The problem is that either way 24th-century Data succeeds, so they aren't discredited.   That's a smart plot,  but I don't find it very credible.   44th-century Data should have a better plan and not get defeated by his 2000-year younger self when he should much smarter/wiser plus have the benefit of fore-knowledge.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I agree.  But like I said, it's only an implication.  The story only involves the future (44th Century) and the Pakled ship in 2364.  It only makes some passing statements at the end about how he hopes to succeed by establishing a power base (which is implied to be the Borg of "Descent").